# Surfer Grid Contour - Inserting a buffer (river) to contours?

Tags: buffer, contour, surfer

Using Surfer, I am making contours using a grid. I have a river running through my extent, that I need the contours to not cross over. How can I create this buffer? I can add a shapefile of the river into my Surfer plot, but do not know where to go from there. Any tips?

As is, I am exporting my contours as a shapefile, uploading in ArcGIS Pro, and hand-editing to account for the river.

Comment: If you are open to making your contours in ArcGIS Pro instead, there is a Contour with Barriers tool that will do exactly what you want. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/contour-with-barriers.htm

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the spatial analyst extension (really would be helpful!)

Answer (score 0):

In Surfer, you can use the river as a breakline when gridding. That will prevent the contours from crossing over and use the river during the gridding process. The polyline representing the river does need to have a Z value associated with it.

Breaklines can only be used from BLN files though, so what you can do is first convert the SHP to a BLN file. How you do this best though depends if the SHP has a Z value associated with the polyline or not.

1. So first click **Home | New Map | Base**, select the SHP and click *Open*.
2. If the polyline already has a Z value (e.g. it's listed as a *3D Polyline* in **Contents | Base**, or if it's a regular *Polyline* object but you have the Z value associated with it saved as an attribute), the easiest way is to use v28 (currently in Beta). Right click over the *Base* layer and click **3D View**. This will view the polyline in 3D. Select *Vector Data | Base* layer in the 3D View **Contents**. If it was a regular *Polyline* object with Z as an attribute, click the **Z coordinate** tab in **Properties** and make sure the Z coordinates is set to the right Z attribute. Then click *Save Vector Data* and save to a BLN file. The Z value is preserved.
3. If the polyline does not already have a Z value in it (e.g. it's listed as simply *Polyline* in **Contents | Base** and there is no attribute for the Z), then it's a slightly different process. Right click over the *Base* layer and in **Properties** click the *Save File* button (on the same line as *Input file*). Then save it as a BLN file. Now we just need to add Z values to it. Click **File | Open in Worksheet**, select the BLN file and click *Open*. You'll see data values in columns A and B (this is X and Y). Now add the Z values in column C. You'll need add a Z value for each vertex of the polyline. It can be the same for each vertex, or it can be different. Once the Z values are all added, click **File | Save** and **File | Close**.
4. Once you have a BLN file for the river, you can use it during gridding! Click **Home | Grid Data**.
5. In the Grid Data process, on step 1, select the data, data columns and gridding method you wish. The gridding method needs to support breaklines (view these on the [Help page](https://surferhelp.goldensoftware.com/griddata/Breaklines.htm)). Click *Next*.
6. One the **Options** page, under **Breaklines**, load the BLN file as a breakline file. Click *Next* and complete the gridding as usual.

Now when you load the new grid as a contour map, you can see the breakline area. You can add the BLN (or SHP) back as a base layer, so you can see the river through the contours.

If that doesn't work for any reason, please contact Surfer support at support@goldensoftware.com!

I will also add your request to the suggestion database to support SHP files as Breakline files, so you wouldn't have to convert it to a BLN - that would save you a step or two.

To use Surfer beta, if you have active maintenance, you can see instructions [here](https://support.goldensoftware.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026306553-What-is-Surfer-Beta-and-how-can-I-participate).  If you do not have active maintenance, again please contact support@goldensoftware.com and mention this stack exchange post.

Comment: Thank you for this. I do not see where the "Save Vector Data" option is in order to save as a BLN file?

Comment: Hi Maggie - The Save Vector Data is a new feature for the 3D View, and currently it's only in Surfer Beta version (v28). If you have an active maintenance for Surfer 27, you can click File | Online | Try Beta Version.   If you do not have active maintenance for Surfer, please contact support@goldensoftware.com with an email to my attention (Kari) and mention this stack exchange post. Thanks!